# If lua_pcall returns error, are there still return values left on the stack?

Tags: lua, lua-c++-connection

Suppose I'm calling a Lua function from C which returns one result. If it returns an error, will the results still be on the stack?

For example, should the first `lua_pop` in the following code exist?

```
if (lua_pcall(L, nArgs, 1, 0)) {
   lua_pop(L, 1); //should this exist?
   DisplayLuaError(L);
   return -1;
} else {
   int x = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
   lua_pop(1);
   return x;
}
```

Comment: If there's unexpected error caught, then why do you expect any meaningful results from the lua function on stack? Lua manual clearly indicate there's only one value on stack returned in case of failure, and that's the error messages. lua_pop(L,1) should be a part of DisplayLuaError(), and not performed before displaying the error.